# jquery script not working well with turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I have an index in my app, whose view includes some filtering options. Once these are selected, results are being filtered. It's all nice except that when first getting into the index, all this scripting does not work and the page needs to be reloaded in order to function properly. I have tried using the `jquery.turbolinks` gem, didn't do anything.
Any suggestions?

**index.html.erb:**

```
<% content_for :on_document_ready_js_script do %> #this being yielded on layout

    $("#er_filters").change(function() {
        var url = "/examinee_registrations.js";  // grab the URL from the form action value.
    $.get(url, $("form").serialize()); 
   });

<% end %>


<div id="title">
    <h1> 
        <%=t("examinee_registration.title")%>
        <% if @location_id %>
            <span id="<%=@location_id%>"> <%=t("for") + " #{Location.find(@location_id).name}" %> </span>
        <% end %>
    </h1>
</div>
<br>
    <%= form_tag examinee_registrations_url(format: "xls"), method: :get do %>
        <div id="er_filters">
            <br>
            <%= hidden_field_tag 'location_id', @location_id %>
            <%= label_tag 'from_date', t("from_date")+':' %>
            <%= date_field_tag "from_date" %>
            <br>
            <%= label_tag 'to_date', t("to_date")+':' %>
            <%= date_field_tag "to_date" %>
            <br>
            <%= label_tag 'hide_open', t("examinee_registration.hide_open")+':' %>
            <%= check_box_tag "hide_open", true, false  %>
            <br>
            <%= label_tag 'hide_closed', t("examinee_registration.hide_closed")+':' %>
            <%= check_box_tag "hide_closed", true, false  %>
        </div>
        <%= submit_tag t('export_to_excel') %>
    <% end %>

<br>
<%= link_to create_title('examinee_registration.single')+"ה", new_examinee_path %>
<hr>


<div id='er_div' >
    <%= render 'examinee_registrations' %>
</div>
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**index.js.erb:**

```
$("#er_div").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'examinee_registrations') %>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using turbolinks? Unless you have a really good, well thought-through reason, where nothing else than turbolinks is the answer, I would suggest that you get rid of it.

Comment: well, I was just there with the app. disabling it did not affect performance, at least not in a noticeable way. although disabling would suffice in my case, I'd still wanna know how can it be really solved.

Comment: While I agree that "the right solution" is nice. Disabling an unneeded feature to make a needed one work is the pragmatic approach :)